# Выполнение Service в бэкграунде

Tags: android-service, android, java, service

Есть сервис который выполняет какие то действия.

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GPSTrackerService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

При нажатии кнопки назад или домой, сервис уничтожается и перестает работать до тех пор пока пользователь заново не откроет приложение.
Как сделать так, что бы он выполнялся вне зависимости от открытости **MainActivity**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть как раз для этого специальный метод startForeground(id, notif). Вызовите его в onStartCommand() и ваш сервис никогда не грохнется  будет работать постоянно

Answer (score 0):

можно воспользоваться классом AlarmManager

у него есть достаточно много тонких настроек, которые позволят запускать приложение в определенное время и глушить. с помощью него например написан стандартный будильник. но нужно быть внимательным в отношении API 19, поскольку там изменен механизм работы.